# .each() problems, jquery

Tags: jquery, each, html

I am trying to get the number inside of a `<span>` I am using `.each()` to find all the `span`s but having problems getting the number inside of it.  I would like to attach the number in the span to the image name, but no luck??

Code:

```
var _td = $("td.tri-img span");
$.each(_td, function(i, val){
    $(val).html();
console.log(val);

var _img = $('.wrap-graph.relative img');
var _img_src = 'img/triangle' + val + '.png';
_img.attr('src', _img_src);
});
```

HTML:

```
<td class="tri-img"><img class="one"src="" alt="" ><span>11</span></td>
<td class="tri-img"><img class="two" src="" alt="" ><span>33</span></td>
<td class="tri-img"><img class="three" src="" alt="" ><span>44</span></td>
<td class="tri-img"><img class="four" src="" alt="" ><span>66</span></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**:

```
$("td.tri-img span").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prev('img').attr('src', 'img/triangle'+$this.text()+'.png');
});
```

EDIT: If you want to clean the text of any non-digits, do this:

```
$("td.tri-img span").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        text  = $this.text().replace(/\D/, '');
    $this.prev('img').attr('src', 'img/triangle'+text+'.png');
});
```

Comment: this worked great!! thank you  quick additional question, i want to remove a % inside td.tri-img span, I tried: $("td.tri-img span.tri-val").remove(":contains('&#37;')"); but no luck?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var _img_src = 'img/triangle' + val + '.png';
```

to

```
var _img_src = 'img/triangle' + val.innerHTML + '.png';
```